# Set a cookie for 1 hour and check for it on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, setcookie

I want to do a little animation when an user visits the site but I don't want it to show every time the user switches between the subpages. At the moment it does the animation every time and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited') > -1) {
        // They've been here before.
        alert("hello again");
    }
    else {
        // set a new cookie
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (3600 * 1000));
        document.cookie = "visited=yes;" + "expires=" + d.toUTCString() + ";path=/";
        // slide in navbar
        sleep(100);
        document.getElementById("navlist").style.left = "63%";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple use `sessionStorage` instead of cookies like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(sessionStorage.getItem("visitedBefore") == undefined){
            sessionStorage.setItem("visitedBefore", "1");
            alert("Welcome for the first time!");
    }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qkbmer2p/)

Comment: Will it destroy itself after 1 hour, too?

Comment: No, it will destroy itself if the user closes the web browser tab or the window. This means the animations will not be triggered as long as the user is surfing within the same after the first time the animations have been played.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.